# How to change array to json in php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have this php array

```
$var = $var = explode("[;;]",$result['infoplantilla']);
$numRow = count($var); 
$form = array
        (
            "numRow",$numRow,
            "selectOption",$var,
            "prefijo",$result['prefijo'],
            "Sufijo",$result['sufijo'],
            "Plantilla",$result['descripcion']
            );

echo  json_encode($form);
```

So when I try to return this to the ajax call it return me value something like this .

```
["numRow",2,"selectOption",["baners.Idbaner= INMOMEXICO.ANUNCIO.ID"," monedas.Idmoneda= INMOMEXICO.ANUNCIO.MONEDA"],"prefijo","MXSAEI","Sufijo","-14","Plantilla","SAE"]
```

Which is not a Json string can any one help me out where I am going wrong because supposedly I should get a Json string from the array

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your array is NOT an **associative** array.

Try this:

```
$form = array
        (
            "numRow" => $numRow,
            "selectOption" => $var,
            "prefijo" => $result['prefijo'],
            "Sufijo" => $result['sufijo'],
            "Plantilla" => $result['descripcion']
         );
```

Comment: Yes sure after 10 minutes :) Stack won't let me mark it now

Comment: @Vikram , please dont make unnecessary comments.Only useful comments should remain below the answer.

Comment: @RahulDesai one last question in Jquery I understood I will have to use `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( json )` but how I can get the multidimentional array ? , Like when i write `Obj.selectOption` it returns me a string that has all the values of that array so Its difficult to use then ;

Comment: @Vikram Sorry, your question is not clear to me. Please post a new question on StackOverflow and link me to it so I can help you. Also, if you can add a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem, that would be helpful. :)

Comment: @RahulDesai http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/4wg9oqor/   here  is the fiddle for my problem ; thanks

Comment: @Vikram Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/4wg9oqor/1/ The problem was that, your data was neither a Javascript object nor a JSON. I made a string out of it and parsed.